# Find a non-unique element in a table of rows Java

Tags: java, selenium, element, rows

I am trying to identify and select an element on the page that is NOT unique.  I am combating this by creating a list of rows for the table I am working with (See below) and still getting the wrong element.  Here is the use case:

I need to select the 3rd row in this table so I created a list of elemnets with a "tr" tag.  Once I have the list I go though and look for the specific name, in this caes Octopus, Complex.  Once I find this name I use my WebElement object to findElements that correspond to the amount I want for that row.  In this case circled 105.00.  However I am always getting the first amount in the page, in this example, the highlighted 170.00.  All of the elements for each row are the same name.  I need the WebDriver to only focus on the row I have found and not the entire page.

[image: table]

I have tried to make a list within a list.  The elements are NOT indexed on the page so I cannot just do a get(0) to find what I am looking for.  I tried to findElements within the row element that matched my amount selector.  I have hit a wall for both techniques.  My code so far for this problem is below:

```
    dispatchTable = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#dispatchBoardTable"));
    List<WebElement> dispatchItems = dispatchTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    System.out.println("Looking for " + Accountant.getClientName() + " in Dispatch Board");
    for(WebElement we : dispatchItems){ 

        if(we.equals(null))
            continue;

        //If we find the name we're looking for, get the amount for that name.
        if(we.getText().contains(Accountant.getClientName())){

            clientTotal = we.findElement(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@data-bind, 'text: Amount')]")).getText();
            System.out.println("Total for this client Dispatch Board is: " + clientTotal);
        }
    }
```

Comment: store "seen elements" in a collection and check if the "current element" was already seen using `contains()`?

Comment: `if(we.equals(null))` doesn't make any sense if we is null, you will get a NPE so it will skip everything or fail with an NPE

Comment: can you add html of page you are trying to automate ?

Comment: I'd rather not.  I am not sure of confidentiality on this and Id rather play it safe.  What are you looking for specifically?  Maybe I can add it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like below

```
  clientTotal = we.findElement(By.xpath("td[starts-with(@data-bind, 'text: Amount')]")).getText();
```

Used 'td' instead of '*' off-course we can use any thing.

Comment: This is the solution.  I am not familar with xpath as much as I should be.  Can you explain why //* wouldnt work where td will?  Does //* override my context?

Comment: Yes, here we are appending new xpath to previous we. so we use '//' it may looks like //previous xpath//present which may leads to wrong one. in above we used without '//' so it create xpath like //previous xpath/present which pickups required element. '*' means element having any tag if we say 'td' means element having only td tag.

Comment: Oh ok it makes much more sense now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use below line find xpath
dispatchTable = driver.findElement(By.xpath(""));
Check it is working .
Or 
If you use CSS then check both same data (TD data)CSS selector are same or not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I tried this and still have same behavior.